# Replace strings in columns from a list

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, list, replace

I have a list of words (profanities) blacklisted and I want to retrospectively go through a column in my `Comments` table and replace all occurrences of any of the words in my blacklist with an `*`. The `*` is consistent (so it's not per letter of the word) so a four letter word would still have only one *. I looked up the `Replace` method in the [documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) but it only explains how to do it for one word at a time. Is there a fast way of replacing all occurrences of strings from a whole list of words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace from a list you could use a regex replace with the match `(badword1|bardword2|badword3|etc)`.

There seems to be a [regex-replace extension](https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-regex-replace-ext) for sqlite, but I have not tried it.